# One output and no dismiss

Tags: android

I have two problems, my first one is that i'm only getting one out put "score of 0" I don't know what's wrong with my code. It won't add the integers and keeps them at 0. My second one is that a new pop up comes up and then the okay button to dismiss won't work. Thanks for your help!

```
    package xyz.ashraf.whoisdelasalle;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Ashraf on 3/2/2016.
 */
public class check_Button extends Pop_sallian{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.popwindow_sallian);
        CheckBox concern = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.concern);
        CheckBox faith = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.faith);
        CheckBox respect = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.respect);
        CheckBox education = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.education);
        CheckBox community = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.community);
        TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);

        int con = 0;
        int fai = 0;
        int res = 0;
        int edu = 0;
        int com = 0;

        if (concern.isChecked()) {
            con = con+1;
        }
        if (faith.isChecked()) {
            fai = fai+1;
        }
        if (respect.isChecked()) {
            res = res+1;
        }
        if (education.isChecked()) {
            edu = edu+1;
        }
        if (community.isChecked()) {
            com = com +1;
        }
        int score = con+fai+res+edu+com;

        if(score == 0){
            output.setText("score of 0");
        } else if(score == 1){
            output.setText("score of 1");
        } else if(score == 2){
            output.setText("score of 2");
        } else if(score == 3){
            output.setText("score of 3");
        } else if(score == 4){
            output.setText("score of 4");
        } else if(score == 5){
            output.setText("score of 5");
        } else{
            output.setText("Unknown");
        }
    }
}
```

code where the out put doesn't work^^

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    android:elevation="8dp"

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Are you a Sallian?"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you meet the following prerequisites, if you do you may be a Sallian"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Are you concerened for the poor and Social Justice?"
        android:id="@+id/concern"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you have faith in the presence of God?"
        android:id="@+id/faith"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/concern"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you have Respect for all people?"
        android:id="@+id/respect"
        android:layout_below="@+id/faith"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you value education?"
        android:id="@+id/education"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/respect"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Are you inclusive in your community?"
        android:id="@+id/community"
        android:layout_below="@+id/education"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:checked="false" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ok"
        android:id="@+id/okButton_sallian"
        android:layout_below="@+id/community"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="#FAFAFA"
        android:textColor="#00E676"
        android:elevation="2dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Check"
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:textColor="#00E676"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="#FAFAFA"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/okButton_sallian"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/output"
        android:layout_below="@+id/community"
        android:textColor="#1eff00"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/check"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/check"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/okButton_sallian"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/okButton_sallian"
        android:layout_above="@+id/check"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

xml pop up window where the okay button won't work when the check button is checked^^

```
package xyz.ashraf.whoisdelasalle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by Ashraf on 1/27/2016.
 */
public class Pop_sallian extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.popwindow_sallian);

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int height = dm.heightPixels;

        getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.8),(int)(height*.6));

        Button checkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check);
        checkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Pop_sallian.this, check_Button.class));
            }
        });
        Button okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okButton_sallian);
        okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

java code that creates the pop up^^

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong,I think you are missing listener for your checkbox in your check_Button activity

Comment: Could you explain how?

Comment: when you create the activity, it loads the widgets (checkboxs) from xml. In the time of creation, everything was unchecked. and you are doing your calculations during the creation time. that's why you are always receiving score 0. Try to achieve above logic in checkbox listener. you could observe the difference.

Comment: how would I implement that?

Comment: just google "how to add compound listener to checkbox in android"